# How to send array of string Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6

I want to replace in this code the include_players_ids[] value with array of multiple player ids. I tried body but it says deprecated. Any help please. Guzzle version is 6. I tried ['id', 'id'] and array('id', 'id'). Response is "include_player_ids" should be an array or formatting error

```
$client = new Client();
    try {

        $r = $client->request('POST', 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', [

            'form_params' =>
                [

                'app_id' => 'app_id',

                'include_player_ids[]' => '9cc7691d-04ea-4245-9eed-667f70a218c1',

                'headings' => [
                    'en' => $request->input('title')
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
'form_params' =>
                [

                'app_id' => 'app_id',

                'include_player_ids' => ['9cc7691d-04ea-4245-9eed-667f70a218c1', 'dummy']

                'headings' => [
                    'en' => $request->input('title')
                ]
            ]
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params

Comment: Thank you. I tried that already but one signal says "include_player_ids should be an array"

Comment: I don't understand your purpose

Comment: 'include_player_ids' is an array, hence @NguyenHungThai has Correctly declared the array. This code should not give the same error now.